# How to customize an Execute method of ObjectQuery?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I have a partition-like database schema in my database.

There's one 'partitioning' table named `SITE` and every other table has a foreign key to that table (`SITE\_FK`).

I wrote a partial class for an ObjectContext adding a `SITE\_ID` property and a constructor that sets this property.

Now, after I instantiate an ObjectContext with some `SITE\_ID` I need that every single query built with this ObjectContext tests that `SITE\_FK = SITE\_ID` (which is stored in ObjectContext). It would be best not to have to test for it explicitly in every query in the code but to test it somehow '*internally*' in the ObjectQuery.

The first thought is to add some functionality to ObjectQuery.Execute method that adds one more Where to the Query but I can't find how to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding [`SaveChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500.aspx)?

There are also some [other methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext_methods.aspx) in the `ObjectContext` you'd probably want to consider.